# EE embed inside stash parse process end

Tags: stash, embeds, parse

can I do an embed within a stash:parse with process end?

```
{exp:stash:parse process="end"}
    {embed="index/.homeFeatured"}
{/exp:stash:parse}
```

I just got the the embed line printed on the screen, without parsing.

actually my whole code looks like this:

```
{stash:embed:ech:stash_featured stash:rubricid="0" stash:limit="7"}
{stash:embed:ech:stash_entries stash:rubricid="0" stash:hideFeatured="7"}
{stash:embed:ech:stash_disrupters stash:rubricid="26
{stash:embed:ech:stash_teasers stash:rubricid="41"}

{exp:stash:parse process="end"}
   {in:sert:index/.homeFeatured} // inside here there is my embed which is not getting parsed
   {in:sert:index/.homeBrandnew}
   {in:sert:index/.homeAktuell}
   {in:sert:index/.homeArchive}
{/exp:stash:parse}
```

Comment: by using stash:embed instead of the native EE embed tag, it works. anyway curious to know, even process end sounds like no EE tags are parsed anymore...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stash will not parse EE embeds, only it's own embeds.